# how do i separate the country and accession from within a fasta file

Tags: r, fasta

hi im not good with R but i have a file that contains DNA sequences and i need to have a separate column for country and accession how do i do this?

```
A tibble: 167 x 2
   Header                Sequence                                                           
   <chr>                 <chr>                                                              
 1 United Kingdom |MW05… AGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAAC…
 2 United Kingdom |MW04… ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
 3 France |MT594401.1    AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
 4 France |MT594402.1    AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
 5 Germany |MT845877.1   AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
 6 Germany |MT845878.1   AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
 7 Germany |MT913119.1   ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
 8 United Kingdom |MT87… TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTG…
 9 Germany |MT704816.1   ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
10 Germany |MT704817.1   ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
# … with 157 more rows
```

this is the file as you can see the country and accession number are together and i need to separate these

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` we split at the `"|"`, which we escape with `\\` because it's a special character, and remove white space with `trimws`. Finally `cbind` it to the rest and `setNames` and order columns if we like.

```
res <- cbind(trimws(do.call(rbind, strsplit(d$V2, "\\|"))), d[c(1, 3)])
res <- setNames(res, c("name", "accession", names(d)[-2]))[c(3, 1, 2, 4)]
res
#    V1           name  accession
# 1   1 United Kingdom      MW05…
# 2   2 United Kingdom      MW04…
# 3   3         France MT594401.1
# 4   4         France MT594402.1
# 5   5        Germany MT845877.1
# 6   6        Germany MT845878.1
# 7   7        Germany MT913119.1
# 8   8 United Kingdom      MT87…
# 9   9        Germany MT704816.1
# 10 10        Germany MT704817.1
#                                                                     V3
# 1  AGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAAC…
# 2  ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
# 3  AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
# 4  AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
# 5  AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
# 6  AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
# 7  ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
# 8  TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTG…
# 9  ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
# 10 ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = c("United Kingdom |MW05…", "United Kingdom |MW04…", 
"France |MT594401.1", "France |MT594402.1", "Germany |MT845877.1", 
"Germany |MT845878.1", "Germany |MT913119.1", "United Kingdom |MT87…", 
"Germany |MT704816.1", "Germany |MT704817.1"), V3 = c("AGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAAC…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…", 
"AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…", 
"AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…", 
"AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTG…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
    separate(V2, into = c("name", "accession"), sep="\\s*\\|\\s*")
#   V1           name  accession                                                                  V3
#1   1 United Kingdom      MW05… AGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAAC…
#2   2 United Kingdom      MW04… ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
#3   3         France MT594401.1 AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
#4   4         France MT594402.1 AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…
#5   5        Germany MT845877.1 AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
#6   6        Germany MT845878.1 AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…
#7   7        Germany MT913119.1 ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
#8   8 United Kingdom      MT87… TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTG…
#9   9        Germany MT704816.1 ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
#10 10        Germany MT704817.1 ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = c("United Kingdom |MW05…", "United Kingdom |MW04…", 
"France |MT594401.1", "France |MT594402.1", "Germany |MT845877.1", 
"Germany |MT845878.1", "Germany |MT913119.1", "United Kingdom |MT87…", 
"Germany |MT704816.1", "Germany |MT704817.1"), V3 = c("AGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAAC…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…", 
"AACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGC…", 
"AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…", 
"AACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGG…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"TTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTG…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…", 
"ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTC…"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```